# WordPress CF7 Shortcode with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, contact-form-7

Using Contact Form 7 DB plugin I am able to run the shortcode

```
[cfdb-value form="List Store" filter="store-name=my store"]
```

But I want to use like

```
[cfdb-value form="List Store" filter="store-name=[php] echo $_SESSION['store-name']; [/php]"]
```

the above one is not working, I also tried like

```
echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-value form="Add Store"]');
```

I want to use PHP echo instead of store-name=`my store`

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using it in editor or in php file?

Comment: @K.K.Agarwal - In WP Editor.

Comment: echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-value form="List Store" filter="store-name='.$_SESSION["store-name"].'"]');

Answer (score 0):

You can't evaluate php code inside editor unless you have some plugin installed that will do that, and any such plugin will use [eval()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function. Another problem is that if there are nested shortcodes, handler from outer shortcode must filter the inner one.

There are many plugins for evaluating PHP code that is saved in the database as part of the post. I think that evaluating any PHP code that is not inside .php file is wrong. The main purpose of shortcodes is to give ability to perform that task, to modify the content of the post ( according to the parameters provided in shortcode ), and it should be done inside shortcode handler.

If you want to manually use shortcode do:

```
echo do_shortcode( '[cfdb-value form="List Store" filter="store-name=' . $_SESSION['store-name'] . '"]' );
```